# How to prove that $∇f(x)\cdot x = tf(x) $?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose we have $ t ∈ \mathbb R $ and $ f : \mathbb R^n → \mathbb R $ which satisfies $ f(λx) = λ^tf(x) $ for $ x ∈ \mathbb R^n $, $ λ ∈ \mathbb R $.

I have two questions;

How would I prove that $ ∇f(x)\cdot x = tf(x) $ ?

And how can I verify this formula in case $ n = 2 $ for the
function given by $ f(x, y) = x^2 + 2xy + y^2 $ ?

My initial idea was to use the fact that $f(x) = \frac{f(λx)}{(λ^t)} $ and then find $ ∇f(x) $ of this.

I'm struggling to find a solution that I can follow step by step, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to be fancy with $f(x) = f(\lambda x)/\lambda^t$. Just use the coordinate definition of $∇$ and compute by hand $∇f(x)$.

Comment: For reference, this is Euler's theorem on homogenous functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $\lambda$ should be positive. Second, to derive [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Positive_homogeneity) (this is how it's called), just take the derivative with respect to $\lambda$ in both sides of $f(\lambda x) = \lambda ^t f(x)$ and use the chain rule:

- the left-hand side gives $\sum _{i = 1} ^n \dfrac {\partial f} {\partial x_i} (\lambda x) \ x_i = (\nabla f)(\lambda x) \cdot x$
- the right-hand side gives $t \lambda ^{t-1} f(x)$.

Being both sides of an equality, these expressions must be equal, so evaluate them both in $\lambda =1$. This is it.

In the concrete case of $n=2$ and $f(x,y) = x^2 + 2xy + y^2$, notice that

$$f( \lambda x, \lambda y) = (\lambda x)^2 + 2( \lambda x) (\lambda y) + (\lambda y)^2 = \lambda^2 (x^2 + 2xy + y^2) = \lambda ^2 f(x,y) ,$$

so in this case $t=2$. You get $\dfrac {\partial f} {\partial x} (x,y) x + \dfrac {\partial f} {\partial y} (x,y) y = 2 f(x,y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: differentiate your equation $f(λx) = λ^tf(x)$ w.r.t. $\lambda$ and then set $\lambda=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in \Bbb R^n$ be fixed and define $$g_x(\lambda)=f(\lambda x)-\lambda^tf(x)$$
Then, $g(\lambda)=0$ for every $\lambda$, therefore $g$ is constant. Thus $g'(\lambda)=0$ for every $\lambda$. In particular,
$$0=g'(1)=\langle x,\nabla f(x)\rangle-tf(x).$$

---

For your second question:

Note that $\nabla f(x,y) = (2x+y,2y+x)^T$ and thus $$\langle (x,y),\nabla f(x,y)\rangle=x(2x+y)+y(2y+x)=2f(x,y)$$

Comment: Reference: http://people.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/Notes/EulerHomogeneity.pdf